# Java - Bitwise comparisons and shifting of bits

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I need a little explanation of the following statement, What is it doing?:

```
int result = 154 + (153 << 8) + (25 << 16) + (64 << 24);
/* what would be the value of result after this line and how it is calculated
Why we need this? */
```

Comment: Well, how much do you not understand? What's the context of this? Is it your homework?

Comment: See [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`(153 << 8)`** is equivalent to **`153 * pow(2, 8)`**

You are actually shifting your bits towards left..

Also: -

**`(153 >> 8)`** is equivalent to **`153 / pow(2, 8)`**

You can guess why.. This is actually shifting bits towards right..

E.G: -

```
3 => 0011

3 << 2 is equal to 1100 -> (Which is code for 12)

3 >> 2 is equal to 0000 -> (Which is code for 0) -> you can see - **(3 / 4 = 0)**
```

**NOTE** :- Note that the `right shifting rounds off towards negative infinity`..

**For E.G: -**

```
-3 >> 1 --> -2 (-1.5 is rounded to -2)
```

Lets see how it happens: -

**In binary string representation: -**

```
-3 ==> 11111111111111111111111111111101

-3 >> 1 ==> 11111111111111111111111111111110 (-3 / 2 = -1.5 -> rounded to -2)
```

(Note the left most bit is filled by the  bit that was present at the left most end before shift (1 in this case))

So, the value becomes, **-2** (for -3>>1, which is greater than `-3`)
This happens for negative numbers.. `Right shifting a negative number gives a number greater than the original number..`

Which is contrary to the positive number where the left most bit will be filled by `0`... Thus `value obtained will be less than the original..`

```
3 ==>  00000000000000000000000000000011

3 >> 1 ==> 00000000000000000000000000000001 (3 / 2 = 1.5 -> rounded to 1)
```

(So left most bit remains 0. So, the value is 1 (less than 3), i.e., value is rounded off towards negative infinity and becomes 1 from 1.5)

Similarly you can devise results for `left-shifting` positive and negative number..

Comment: That's somewhat misleading - shifting left doesn't necessarily create a result bigger than the left operand, and that equivalence for shifting right is only correct when the left operand is non-negative (and also doesn't always make numbers smaller - negative numbers get bigger).

Comment: @harold Would you please give an example of your claim "shifting left doesn't necessarily create a result bigger than the left operand"?

Comment: @umirza47 `-1 << 1`, `2 << 31`, or even nicer, `0x40000000 << 1` and there's `0 << anything` of course

Comment: Ok better, could you add that the equivalent for right shifts is only valid for positive numbers then? (otherwise shifting rounds the other way than dividing does)

Comment: @harold.. Added.. Do let me know, if I have missed something..  :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is 1075419546. The left shift operator is basically addings 0s to the binary representations of the decimal numbers so this would simply to

154 + 153 * 2^8 + 25 * 2^16 + 64*2^24

So you can convert 153 to its binary representation, then add 8 zeros and convert back to decimal etc etc..

Answer (score 0):

in practical terms, if you use the given operator on a math expression it has the same meaning as the following:

123 << n is exactly the same as 123 * 2 ^ n

For example, 2 << 2 is 2 * 2 ^ 2 which is 8 or the same as 1000

Otherwise, you are just shifting bits to the left:

3 = 11 then 3 << 2 = 1100.

Hope it makes it clear.